# How can I avoid this rendering gap in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have the following Dart code:

```
[...]
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(APP_BAR_TITLE,
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'custom', fontSize: 24)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                children: [ImageView(context), RoundedBox()]),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 4, right: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    AuthorAndData(context),
                    Body(context),
                  ],
                ))
            //  Floating button
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget ImageView(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(newsElement.imageurl)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget RoundedBox() {
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 249, 249, 249),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
    );
  }

  Widget AuthorAndData(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          newsElement.autor,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        ),
        Text(
            getCurrentDate(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget Body(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
          child: Text(
            newsElement.title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
          child: Html(data: newsElement.fulltext),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  String getCurrentDate() {
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(newsElement.publishedUp);
    return formatted;
  }
```

Everything is fine but as a result I can see some kind of rendering issue gap between the RoundedBox and the Row:

[image]

But if you scroll down the column a little bit, sometimes it looks fine:

[image]

Is something wrong with my coding or is this a rendering issue by Dart / Flutter? It is reproducible within Android Studio virtual devices, Android and iOS physical devices.